# Promise throwing unhandled error on resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have the below code but when resolve is called it throws:

```
Possibly unhandled Error: undefined
    at Promise$_rejecter (c:\projects\Test\promiseftp\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:602:58)
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (c:\projects\Test\promiseftp\index.js:45:33)
    at WriteStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at fs.js:1598:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

CODE BELOW:

```
var Client = require('ftp');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var Promise = require('bluebird');


var c = new Client();

var connectionProperties = {
    host: "myhost",
    user: "myuser",
    password: "mypwd"
};

c.connect(connectionProperties);

var downloadFiles = new Promise.method(function () {
    return new Promise(function (reject, resolve) {
        c.on('ready', function () {
            c.list(function (err, list) {
                if (err) reject(err);
                list.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
                    //Ignore directories
                    if (element.type === 'd') {
                        console.log('ignoring directory ' + element.name);
                        return;
                    }
                    //Ignore non zips
                    if (path.extname(element.name) !== '.zip') {
                        console.log('ignoring file ' + element.name);
                        return;
                    }

                    c.get(element.name, function (err, stream) {
                        if (err) reject(err);
                        console.log(element.name);
                        stream.once('close', function () {
                            //c.end();
                            //resolve();
                        });

                        var pipeaction = stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(element.name));
                        pipeaction.on('close', function () {
                            console.log('close');
                            //THROWS HERE!
                            resolve();
                        });

                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });

});


downloadFiles().then(function () {
    console.log('woot');
});
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: On a side note - when you use `Promise.method` you can skip the whole 'return new Promise` bit, you can instead - like you would in a .then call - return to resolve and throw to reject. Also, I'd promisify the ftp client too if I were you. Also, does `close` get logged? Does it get to the `close` event?

Comment: Close gets logged twice. Even after making the ftp promisifed I get the same errors

Comment: You cannot resolve a promise twice, looks like that's a problem with `forEach`. However, are you sure that it throws on `resolve()`? The error looks more like `reject()` was called.

Comment: @Bergi he has defined `new Promise(function(reject, resolve){})` - the parameters should be `resolve, reject` instead. When the parameters are in wrong order, calling `resolve()` is equivalent to calling real `reject(undefined)`

Answer (score 3):

Please don't mix callbacks and promises, look at how simple it can be:

```
when(c, "ready").then(function(){
    return c.listAsync();
}).filter(function(element) {
    return element.type !== "d" && path.extname(element.name) === ".zip";
}).map(function(element) {
    return c.getAsync(element.name).then(function(stream) {
        return when(stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(element.name)), "close");
    })
}).then(function(){
    console.log("all files copied");
});
```

Boilerplate:

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var Client = require('ftp');
Promise.promisifyAll(Client.prototype);

var c = new Client();

var connectionProperties = {
    host: "myhost",
    user: "myuser",
    password: "mypwd"
};

c.connect(connectionProperties);

function when(obj, event) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        obj.on(event, resolve);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working and blogged the result - http://blog.jonathanchannon.com/2014/03/22/using-node-and-ftp-with-promises/